# Task for invalid number in Python

Tags: python, logical-operators

I need to write a program where numbers 100 to 200 and 0 are declared as valid. Everything else is invalid. When you put a invalid number in, it should print invalid but if the number is valid the nothing should print nothing in the terminal.

I wrote something but then when i give 155 as input it still says that it's invalid when it shouldn't print anything. Any ideas how I can fix it?

```
number = int(input())

if number < 100 or number > 200 or number != 0:
    print('invalid')
else:
    print()
```

Comment: You wrote `if ... number != 0: print('invalid')`.

Comment: Now that you have edited the question, maybe you should implement the logic as stated. It will be easier than trying to reason about the negative!

Comment: 150 is certainly not equal to 0, so the code prints "invalid", just like you told it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change number==0 instead of number!=0

```
number = int(input())

if number == 0 or (number >= 100 and number <= 200):
    print()
else:
    print('invalid')
```

Comment: `number == 0 or (100 <= number and number <= 200)` should be used to consider 100 and 200 as valid numbers too